# I am building a mean stack chat app using socket.io . But the message doesnt get appended in the client

Tags: node.js, angular, express, socket.io, chat

I am trying to build a mean stack chat app. I'm using angular as client, node js and express in backend. For real time updates, I'm using Socket.io. My backend is working fine. But in frontend, the messages are not getting appended properly when it's inside of the callback passed to on().

Here is my chat.component.ts.

````
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth.service';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-chat',
  templateUrl: './chat.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chat.component.scss']
})
export class ChatComponent implements AfterViewInit {
 
  @ViewChild('mainContainer', { static: false }) mainContainer: ElementRef = {} as ElementRef;
  username: string = '';
  socket: any = '';
 
  constructor(private authSv: AuthService,
    private renderer: Renderer2) { }
 
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
    this.username = this.authSv.username;
    //this.append(`Suresh has joined the chat`, 'right');//Line 1
    this.socket.emit('new-user-joined', this.username);
 
    this.socket.on('user-joined', (name: string) => {
      console.log(`${name} has joined the chat`); //Line 2
      this.append(`${name} has joined the chat`, 'right'); //Line 3
    });
  }
 
  append(message: string, position: string) {
    const msgElem = this.renderer.createElement('div');
    this.renderer.setProperty(msgElem, 'innerText', message);
    this.renderer.addClass(msgElem, 'message');
    this.renderer.addClass(msgElem, position);
    console.log(msgElem); //Line 4
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.mainContainer.nativeElement, msgElem);
  }
}```

Issue:

In case of Line 1, the div correctly gets appended to the mainContainer.
[![app snapshot][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cs6C.png

In Line 2, the console.log gets correctly printed. But in Line 3, where I'm calling the append(), the div doesn't get appended to the mainContainer. I inspected developers tools and there also i saw nothing got appended to the container.  Line 4 correctly prints - (<div _ngcontent-ng-c352222155="" class="message right">test2 has joined the chat</div>). I'm not sure why this is happening. Can you please help me? I'm stuck here.
````

Comment: afaik line 4 should return an element not just text, if the element is created there is no explanation why it is not added to mainContainer. And with the previous correct behavior this is strange. Could you check\call your method manually to test it out

Comment: Line 4 returns div element -----> <div _ngcontent-ng-c352222155="" class="message right">test2 has joined the chat</div>. But it doesn't get appended to the mainContainer. Even when I inspect HTML elements using dev tools, this new div is not there inside of mainContainer.